# Flutter Web - Textfield perform unexpected result when pressed the enter for the new line. (issue for Non-English only)

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, web, newline, textfield

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txe5c.png)

I've got the issue about textfield which it appears too much new lines when I typed Thai character and then pressed enter for new line. You can see the picture I attached.

It happens only Chrome and Internet Explorer browser, while Safari working fine (Android and IOS working fine as well).

This issue is not a problem for English character. But I think it is an issue for some non-english because I tested on Myanmar character, they got the same problem as picture attached.

I assumed the problem is likely to '\n'

Can someone suggest me how to resolve this ?

Note: I do not want to use to not allow RegExp(\n) becuase the new line in textfield is a necessary for users to input the data.